# Nginx responds only to default site config

Tags: nginx, debian, web-server, virtualhost

I got some troubles with nginx. I registered two domains with freenom.com: domain1.tk and domain2.tk. I changed the nameservers and so my server is successfully linked to freenom. It works if I leave default config. But, since I need to have 2 sites in 1 server, I followed this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 and created two config files in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and made two symbolik links, and it doesn't work. Nginx seems to always answer to default config for each request, both domain1.tk and domain2.tk and obviously also the server ip. But if I rename "default" in "default.bak" and I reload nginx service, it is unable to connect, neither if I type the ip in the browser. So nginx only answers to default. Here are the various configs:

**default config file**:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #}
    location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

**domain1.tk config file:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/domain1.tk;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain1.tk www.domain1.tk;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**domain2.tk config file:**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html/domain2.tk;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain2.tk www.domain2.tk;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**nginx.conf:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

edit:

```
# ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
default  domain1.tk  domain2.tk
```

Comment: Do the Nginx error / access logs have anything relevant? If so please edit your question to include them.

Comment: nope, they haven't.

Comment: Make triple sure that your site config files are included by the nginx.conf include - check the directory and permissions. If that doesn't help do a curl of each site and edit your question to include any and all related log entries related to that curl. Don't just give us a dump of logs, show the curl, then the related error / access log entry.

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

Comment: @Tim as you see in the nginx.conf, the include includes "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;" so it's ok. then you told to check directory and permissions... what kind of permissions I should set? also, the access and error logs don't have anything relevant. I tried to delete default config leaving the domain1.tk and domain2.tk configs alone, restarted nginx, and tried to enter in the sites... and as expected, it is unable to connect. I checked the access and error logs, and there isn't my connection attempt

Comment: @Paul I edited the question

Comment: The nginx daemon probably runs as root. I don't even know if things can be hidden from root. This is probably a question for someone who's more experienced with Linux that I am. I expect you've done something simple wrong, but spotting that simple mistake may take a real expert sysadmin.

Comment: I see you resolved the issue for yourself, which is excellent. Please be sure to mark your answer as the answer for this question. Also, I meant to suggest using the command `ls -alF`, as that will print more information. The problem seemed clearly to be related to the symlinks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved. In that guide, it's written to use the command `ln -s` but it will never work this way. I finally find out after several days that the correct command is `ls` without the option `-s`

Comment: I am really most familiar with Ubuntu, which has slightly different commands from Debian. The `ln -s` command is the correct command to use in Ubuntu, which is what the DO tutorial is written for.

Comment: ln -s is about soft linking a file, ls is about listing files

Comment: @Paul yep... I runned debian and I though that ubuntu instructions and debian istructions were aproximetely the same.. Cause ubuntu is debian based